# An Opera bug: auto triggering the browse input when a text link is clicked

Tags: jquery, file-upload, click, onclick, opera

following up on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7132553/jquery-trigger-how-can-i-trigger-the-browse-file-in-the-input-when-i-click-on-a) I made before, I just found out that it does not work on Opera!

How do I fix it?

Here is the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/T5QsA/) for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems like due to security policies triggering click on the input type=`file` is not allowed/supported in some browsers and opera is one of them

see this answer [input type file in Opera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5936909/input-type-file-in-opera/6026101#6026101)

Answer (score 0):

You can not trigger a file dialog from JavaScript in Opera. I'm somewhat surprised if other browsers allow this..

It is still possible to do what you want by placing an invisible file input on top of your text link. To make it invisible, you can for example style it with `opacity:0`. This way, the users will get the impression that they are clicking a text link while the click will actually hit the file input and trigger the file dialog.